# how to make a custom error page not found in apex 3.2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an apex program that i want to make a custom error page for it instead of the following default message that is been displayed when i call a non existing page.
**apex version is 3.2** 
[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I did in 3.x, but I'm not sure it would capture this particular scenario?
http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2010/09/jquery-error-page-replacement.html

How are people opening pages that don't exist.

Comment: it is a quality assurance requirement from the company it self that if you change the page number in the link it shows a custom error page

Comment: Have you also configured session state protection to stop URL tampering? This may make the error shown more consistent, though still limited in 3.2 with regard to handling.